# Vertical orientation degree - Android

Tags: android, android-orientation

Anyone knows how to get smooth vertical orientation degree in Android?

I already tried OrientationEventListener as shown below but it's very noisy. already tried all rates, Normal, Delay, Game and Fastest, all shown the same result.

```
myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {
         orientaion = arg0;

       Log.i("orientaion", "orientaion:" + orientaion);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are two things going on that can affect what you need.

1. *Sensor delay*. Android provides four different sensor delay modes: **SENSOR_DELAY_UI**, **SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL**, **SENSOR_DELAY_GAME**, and **SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST**, where **SENSOR_DELAY_UI** has the longest interval between two data points and **SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST** has the shortest. The shorter the interval the higher data sampling rate (number of samples per second). Higher sampling rate gives you more "responsive" data, but comes with greater noise, while lower sampling rate gives you more "laggy" data, but more smooth.
2. *Noise filtering*. With the above in mind, you need to decide which route you want to take. Does your application need fast response? If it does, you probably want to choose a higher sampling rate. Does your application need smooth data? I guess this is obviously YES given the context of the question, which means you need noise filtering. For sensor data, noise is mostly high frequency in nature (noise value oscillates very fast with time). So a [**low pass filter (LPF)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) is generally adequate.

A simple way to implement LPF is [**exponential smoothing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing). To integrate with your code:

```
int orientation = <init value>;
float update_rate = <value between 0 to 1>;
myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {
        orientation = (int)(orientation * (1f - update_rate) + arg0 * update_rate);
        Log.i("orientation", "orientation:" + orientation);
    }
};
```

Larger **update_value** means the resulting data is less smooth, which should be intuitive: if **update_value == 1f**, it falls back to your original code. Another note about **update_value** is it depends on the time interval between updates (related to sensor delay modes). You probably can tune this value to find one works for you, but if you want to know exactly how it works, check the [alpha value definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) under Electronic low-pass filters -> Discrete-time realization.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem showing an artificial horizon on my device. The low pass filter (LPF) solved this issue.

However you need to consider when you use the orientation angle in degrees and apply the LPF on it blindly, the result is faulty when the device is in portrait mode and turned from left to ride or opposite. The reason for this is the shift between 359 and 0 degree. Therefore I recommend to convert the degree into radians and apply the LPF on the sin and cos values of the orientation angle.

Further I recommend to use a dynamic alpha or update rate for the LPF. A static value for the alpha might be perfect on your device but not on any other.

The following class filters based on radians and uses a dynamic alpha as described above:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

Filter {
    private static final float TIME_CONSTANT = .297f;
    private static final float NANOS = 1000000000.0f;
    private static final int MAX = 360;

    private double alpha;
    private float timestamp;
    private float timestampOld;

    private int count;

    private int values[];

    Filter() {
        timestamp = System.nanoTime();
        timestampOld = System.nanoTime();
        values = new int[0];
    }

    int filter(int input) {
        //there is no need to filter if we have only one
        if(values.length == 0) {
            values = new int[] {0, input};
           return input;
        }

        //filter based on last element from array and input
        int filtered = filter(values[1], input);
        //new array based on previous result and filter
        values = new int[] {values[1], filtered};
        return filtered;
    }

    private int filter(int previous, int current) {
        calculateAlpha();
        //convert to radians
        double radPrev = toRadians(previous);
        double radCurrent = toRadians(current);
        //filter based on sin & cos
        double sumSin = filter(sin(radPrev), sin(radCurrent));
        double sumCos = filter(cos(radPrev), cos(radCurrent));
        //calculate result angle
        double radRes = atan2(sumSin, sumCos);
        //convert radians to degree, round it and normalize (modulo of 360)
        long round = round(toDegrees(radRes));
        return (int) ((MAX + round) % MAX);
    }

    //dynamic alpha
    private void calculateAlpha() {
        timestamp = System.nanoTime();
        float diff = timestamp - timestampOld;
        double dt = 1 / (count / (diff / NANOS));
        count++;
        alpha = dt/(TIME_CONSTANT + dt);
    }

    private double filter(double previous, double current) {
        return (previous + alpha * (current - previous));
    }
}
```

For further readings see this [discussion](http://www.kircherelectronics.com/blog/index.php/11-android/sensors/8-low-pass-filter-the-basics).